# RestTemplate is empty

Tags: java

I created a REST Web Service with the tutorial:

http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-rest-example-tutorial-spring-restful-web-services

But I am getting a 404 Error running the client. Debugging I found out that in class RestTemplate, method doWithRequest at line 504:

```
List<MediaType> allSupportedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
```

`allSupportedMediaTypes` is empty.
The URI is http://localhost:8080/FIRST_REST; in the pom.xml I have FIRST_REST and FIRST_REST, but maybe the URI is wrong.

I don't know how I will get a response; I am going to keep watching this link.

Comment: Can you add your web.xml and controller java file?

Answer (score -1):

If you're getting a 404 that means the URL you're querying does not exist.